# Installing postfix - Problems with apt-get

Tags: apt, email, postfix

I need to install postfix for sending automatic mails from the ubuntu terminal.
I tried with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

But I got the following errors:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
postfix
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main postfix amd64 2.11.0-1ubuntu1   Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postfix/postfix_2.11.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
--fix-missing?
```

I have also run:

> sudo apt-get update

and I got this:

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease    
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg   Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg   Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thank you in advance

P.S.: My ubuntu version is 14.04LTS and I am running it by VMware Workstation 12 Player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you don't have an internet connection. If you do have, try

```
ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

Incase that does not work, try

```
host -v us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

If there are any errors in you DNS connection, they'll show up here.

Comment: If you think the answer helped, just accept the answer so that people can view it if they have similar issues